# Text after a table (which will not fit inside the div) is appearing within the table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've done a lot of research in this (it seems to be asked a lot) but nothing I have tried has worked. I'm using jQuery Mobile. Here's my relevant code:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:220px;">
  <table style="width:100%; word-wrap: break-word; table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="images/Products/Carrot.svg"></td>
      <td height="20">Carrot</td>
      <td height="20">$9.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="images/Products/Raspberry.svg"></td>
      <td height="20">Raspberry</td>
      <td height="20">$3.49</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

There are about 11 extra table rows with text in those, but posting them would be redundant. Ideally, what I would like (this is being displayed on a phone screen) is a small table that you could scroll through, and text underneath it. However, when I try and put a paragraph in a div outside of the table's container it puts it inside the table and scrolls with the table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery .append() function on first div. So it will add content after table

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what u want.

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:220px;overflow:auto;">
  <table style="width:100%; word-wrap: break-word; table-layout:fixed;">
    <tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/550cdda1fabb8596d60b256ba1c73b05?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG"></td>
      <td height="20">Carrot</td>
      <td height="20">$9.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/550cdda1fabb8596d60b256ba1c73b05?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG"></td>
      <td height="20">Raspberry</td>
      <td height="20">$3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/550cdda1fabb8596d60b256ba1c73b05?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG"></td>
      <td height="20">Raspberry</td>
      <td height="20">$3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/550cdda1fabb8596d60b256ba1c73b05?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG"></td>
      <td height="20">Raspberry</td>
      <td height="20">$3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/550cdda1fabb8596d60b256ba1c73b05?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG"></td>
      <td height="20">Raspberry</td>
      <td height="20">$3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/550cdda1fabb8596d60b256ba1c73b05?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG"></td>
      <td height="20">Raspberry</td>
      <td height="20">$3.49</td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/550cdda1fabb8596d60b256ba1c73b05?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG"></td>
      <td height="20">Raspberry</td>
      <td height="20">$3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/550cdda1fabb8596d60b256ba1c73b05?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG"></td>
      <td height="20">Raspberry</td>
      <td height="20">$3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/550cdda1fabb8596d60b256ba1c73b05?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG"></td>
      <td height="20">Raspberry</td>
      <td height="20">$3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/550cdda1fabb8596d60b256ba1c73b05?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG"></td>
      <td height="20">Raspberry</td>
      <td height="20">$3.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20"><img height="20" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/550cdda1fabb8596d60b256ba1c73b05?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG"></td>
      <td height="20">Raspberry</td>
      <td height="20">$3.49</td>
    </tr>
  </table>      
</div>
<div>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </div>
```